# GPG error with http://volatile.debian.org : 'The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2'

Tags: apt, gpg

I am currently trying to add a new repository to apt-get but it is not working.

I'm adding it like this:

```
deb http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile wheezy/volatile non-free
```

Then I get this error:

```
Get:11 http://volatile.debian.org wheezy/volatile Release [7626 B]
Ign http://volatile.debian.org wheezy/volatile Release
E: GPG error: http://volatile.debian.org wheezy/volatile Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

My system is running on Debian 7.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Volatile was discontinued with Squeeze](https://lists.debian.org/debian-volatile-announce/2012/msg00000.html); the replacement is *suite*-updates (in your case, wheezy-updates) on the standard mirrors:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates main
```

You can add `contrib non-free` if necessary.