# PDF: Using Terminal

Tags: command-line, text-processing, pdf

I tried creating a PDF file using terminal . I wrote "vi New.pdf". It created the file. Now that when i trying to double click and open it . It said something like :-

> The file "New.pdf" could not be opened.
>   It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn't require.

Why it is saying like that. How can i fix it.?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange and to Unix&Linux.  For future reference: (1) Saying “using Terminal” is about as useful/relevant for questions like this as saying “I typed `vi New.pdf` ***on my keyboard***.”  Questions are “about Terminal” only when they are related specifically to the operation of the terminal interface; e.g., scrolling, resizing the window, using the window menus and shortcut keys for menu functions, etc.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Far more important information is the operating system (OS) that you are using: e.g., CentOS, Debian, Ubuntu, etc… (and what version).  (2½) You should probably mention what shell you’re using (e.g., bash, dash, fish, tcsh, zsh, etc., …) but (a) almost everybody is using bash, and (b) unless your question concerns characters like `&`, `|`, `;`, `<`, `>`, `$`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, or ``\``, it’s probably not shell-related.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Question titles are allowed to be fairly long.  I would advise keeping them shorter than [100 characters](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202558/80216), but you can make them longer than that if appropriate.  ***Do*** try to make them a bit more about *what the question is about*; e.g., “Creating a PDF file with `vi`”.  That makes it easier for people to judge quickly whether a question is something they might be able to answer.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Conversely, once the question has been answered, a good title (and good tags) make it easier for future users to judge quickly whether it is something they might be able to learn something from.  (But your question currently has just about the right level of detail; don’t leave out information just because it’s mentioned in the title or referenced in the tag(s).)

Answer (score 3):

PDF is not exactly plain text file. So you should create text file and then convert it to pdf. First command create PS file from text file. Second get this PS file and create pdf file

```
a2ps <text filename>
ps2pdf <ps filename>
```

Comment: i typed a2ps New.txt.
said command not found.

Comment: man a2ps showed " No Manual entry for a2ps ".
i am working on Kali , Os x.

Comment: install the package: sudo apt-get install a2ps ps2pdf

Comment: it said sudo: apt-get : command not found.

Comment: OK, so use your package manager and install packages a2ps and ps2pdf

Comment: Sorry. but i don't know where i can find that packet manager. really sorry.

Comment: Please check this page: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/03/23/how-to-install-software-on-kali-linux/

Comment: It's "package manager", not "packet manager".  Which distribution of Linux are you using?

Comment: My mistake :), yes, it is package manager

Comment: I am using Os: yosemite.

Comment: Also using Virtual Box i am operating kali.

Comment: I post above how to install in Kali, have no idea about OS X

Comment: Okay, but are you trying to do your PDF stuff in the Mac OS X guest or in the Kali virtual machine?

Comment: My intention was to create a program to convert Text file into Pdf. if i had that command i would have used system Command inside my c program and can very easily convert .

For that i have to find package.

Answer (score 2):

In OS X or any other OS that has CUPS installed, you can convert a text file to a pdf file without installing new software as follows:

```
    cupsfilter FILE > FILE.pdf
```